# Freezing Table Header Without Access to HTML

Tags: javascript, css

[Preview from the web inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VcSOU.png)
Hi, I am trying to freeze the Table header so that when you scroll, the header remains at a fixed position.

I currently don't have access to HTML because am using a PHP Maker And I don't know how to do that.

Please, can someone assist me freezing the table header with a CSS or a javascript code?

The screenshot of the table contains the table header and tr values
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In CSS you can use

```
.sticky{
    position:fixed;
}
```

For a javascript code, you can use;

```
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

var header = document.getElementById("myHeader");
var sticky = header.offsetTop;

function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
    header.classList.add("sticky");
  } else {
    header.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried this method already and it freezes the whole table instead of the table header. I see reasons being.. The table header is not assigned an ID but instead a Class

Comment: Yes @PrabinAcharya yes but document.getElementsByClassName() doesn't work. But then getbyid works which can't also solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

```
.ewTableHeader{
   position: fixed;
}
```

or

```
.ewTableHeader {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 999;
}
```

Comment: .ewTableHeader{
   position: fixed;
} Seems to work but the table looses it structure and header is sticked to the top.. It becomes in the center of the table as you scroll.

Answer (score 0):

You can always try to do it with CSS/Javascript. Since you can't access the html file, you'll have to add style options to existent classes or add classes with Javascript. The css could be something like this:

```
/* The sticky class is added to the header with JS when it reaches its scroll position */
.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%
}
```

Then you'd need a script to add the sticky class to the header whenever the user scrolled. Something like this:

```
// When the user scrolls the page, execute myFunction 
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

// Get the header
var header = document.getElementsByClassName("ewBox");

// Get the offset position of the navbar
var sticky = header.offsetTop;

// Add the sticky class to the header when you reach its scroll position. Remove "sticky" when you leave the scroll position
function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
    header.classList.add("sticky");
  } else {
    header.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
```

If you don't understand anything, take a look at this [example](https://codepen.io/Kirtle/pen/PRaoag) or don't hesitate to ask me.

Comment: What class is ("ewBox") the table class name is "ewTableHeader"

Comment: I used ewBox but it could be any other class that is showing on the first div. That div is the parent of the table. You won't get good results on just fixing the child.

Comment: And moreover, the table header (thead) does not have an ID so I cant get the element with ID meanwhile calling it with className does not also work.